# Trouble printing my list

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list

If you see where I'm keeping the numbers in the matrix below is a list according to me there are are also keeping all these numbers and when I try to print the list just send me a lot of these:
I@7852e922 this is the memory address? and if the objects as print. Thank you for your attention.

```
package estructurasDeDatos;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Matriz {

    private static Scanner read;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*read = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de filas y columnas: ");
         int f = read.nextInt();
         int c = read.nextInt();*/

        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

        System.out.println("     **   **      ***   ******* ****     *****    ***  *****   *****  ");
        System.out.println("    *   **   *   *   *     *    *   *      *     *     *      *       ");
        System.out.println("    *   **   *  *     *    *    *   *      *    *      *      *       ");
        System.out.println("    *        *  *******    *    ****       *    *      ***     ****   ");
        System.out.println("    *        *  *     *    *    *   *      *    *      *           *  ");
        System.out.println("    *        *  *     *    *    *    *     *     *     *           *  ");
        System.out.println("    *        *  *     *    *    *     *  *****    ***  *****  *****   ");
        System.out.println("###########################################################################");
        int mt [][] = new int[10][10];//Genero la matriz con dos arreglos con una cantidad que yo quiera de
        //filas y columnas.

        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {//Genero un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 100
                num=(int)(Math.random()*100);

                //Asigno el numero generado a la matriz
                mt[i][j]=num;
                ll.push(mt);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {//Imprimo la celdad de la matriz

                System.out.print(mt[i][j]+"\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("###########################################################################");
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("LOS NUMEROS DE LA DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL:");
        System.out.print(mt[0][0]+" "+mt[1][1]+" "+mt[2][2]+" "+mt[3][3]+" "+mt[4][4]+" "+mt[5][5]+" "+mt[6][6]+" "+mt[7][7]+" "+mt[8][8]+" "+mt[9][9]+"\n\n");

        int sumatoriadiap=mt[0][0]+mt[1][1]+mt[2][2]+mt[3][3]+mt[4][4]+mt[5][5]+mt[6][6]+mt[7][7]+mt[8][8]+mt[9][9];

        System.out.println("La sumatoria de la diagonal principal es: \n"+sumatoriadiap);

        System.out.println("El promedio de la diagonal principal es : \n"+sumatoriadiap/10);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        System.out.println("LOS NUMEROS DE LA DIAGONAL SECUNDARIA:");
        System.out.print(mt[0][9]+" "+mt[1][8]+" "+mt[2][7]+" "+mt[3][6]+" "+mt[4][5]+" "+mt[5][4]+" "+mt[6][3]+" "+mt[7][2]+" "+mt[8][1]+" "+mt[9][0]+"\n\n");

        int sumatoriadias=mt[0][9]+mt[1][8]+mt[2][7]+mt[3][6]+mt[4][5]+mt[5][4]+mt[6][3]+mt[7][2]+mt[8][1]+mt[9][0];

        System.out.println("La sumatoria de la diagonal principal es: \n"+sumatoriadias);

        System.out.println("El promedio de la diagonal principal es : \n"+sumatoriadias/10);
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, I don't see where you're printing the list.  Also, you're dealing with arrays, which don't have a `toString()` overridden - what you're seeing is the array's hash code.  Third, you don't have a type on your linked list, which makes working with it...interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're adding the wrong element to your `LinkedList`

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    num = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    mt[i][j] = num;
    ll.push(num); //add the random number to the LinkedList instead of the whole 2 dime array
}
```

Then for printing add something like:

```
System.out.println(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see where you're printing out your list like this:

```
System.out.println(ll);
```

...since you're adding multidimensional arrays inside of an unbound `LinkedList` you have to take special care in printing them.

First:  you have to iterate over the list yourself.

```
for(Object value : ll) {

}
```

Next:  since you don't have generics, you have to cast.  You'd make things easier if you typed your `LinkedList` to `LinkedList<int[][]>`.

Then, you have to use [`Array#deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])), which will get the deep nested values out of the array in a printable and representable fashion.

```
for(Object value : ll) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString((int[][]) value));
}
```